# Criteria Bidirectional Join?

Tags: join, symfony1, symfony-1.4, criteria, propel

i'm working on a symfony project, with propel ORM. In my model, i have a table where its elements can be linked with many elements of the same table, by another table (link table). Some code will explain better:

```
table1:
    id_element: integer;
    [...]
```

and the link table:

```
 link_table:
     id1: fk to table1;
     id2: fk to table1;
```

i need to build a query with Propel Criteria that returns me all the related elements with an specific element. The problem is that the element i want to specify, can be as in id1 field as in id2 field of the link table.

now some of my criteria definition code (not working obviously)

```
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin($linkTable::ID1,$table::ID);
$c->addJoin($linkTable::ID2,$table::ID);
$c->addOr($linkTable::ID1,$specific_id);
$c->addOr($linkTable::ID2,$specific_id);
$result = $table->doSelect($c);
```

and this is a SQL like that I want to generate:

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE table.ID IN
        (SELECT link_table.ID1 FROM link_table
            WHERE link_table.ID2 = "the id that i want"
        )
    OR table.ID IN 
        (SELECT link_table.ID2 FROM link_table
            WHERE link_table.ID1 = "the id that i want"
        )
```

So must i do 2 joins, one for each side of the link table? is there a way to do an "`or-join`"? Please help me!

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Maybe you should re think you solution, this kind of recursive behavior is not encouraged on relational databases. Could you give a little more info about what is this model trying to represent. Most of the time i find myself with complex queries it almost always means i did not think the problem through.

Comment: The table metioned below represents a process. These processes can be related to other processes, forming there a many to many relation, and this relation must be implemented as a link table (so said my college teachers) like i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at last i found a way to do it using criteria:

```
$c = new Criteria();
    $q1 = new Criteria();
    $q1->add($linkPeer::ID1,$my_value);
    result1 = $linkPeer->doSelect($q1);
    foreach($result1 as $result){
        ids1[] = $result->getID();
    }
    $q2 = new Criteria();
    $q2->add($linkPeer::ID2,$my_value);
    result2 = $linkPeer->doSelect($q2);
    foreach($result2 as $result){
        ids2[] = $result->getID();
    }
$ids = array_merge($ids1,$ids2);
$c->add($tablePeer::ID,$ids,Criteria::IN);
$totalResult = $tablePeer->doSelect($c);
```

maybe not the best way but working fine.

Thank you very much for your answers!!

Comment: The unnecessary hydration in the loops will slow down this query quite a bit, depending on the number of iterations. I would swap the `doSelect` on lines 4 and 10 with `doSelectStmt` (and make the necessary adjustments inside each loop) if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't well understand what you need... you have two foreign keys of a table that are both linked to the same table, and so id, and you want an or-join. Why not split in two criteria and so two selections?

Comment: because as a result of my select operation i need an array of unique entities in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking out aloud - that looks functionally identical to this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
LEFT JOIN
    link_table lt1 ON (lt1.id1 = my_table.id)
LEFT JOIN
    link_table lt2 ON (lt2.id2 = my_table.id)
WHERE
    lt1.id2 = X
OR
    lt2.id1 = X
```

If that is identical (obviously do check) then that should be much easier to build a query for. Also, try to use ModelCriteria if you can - I suspect Criteria will be deprecated in Propel 2, and it is a good idea to plan ahead for that.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of `Criteria`, as halfer said, it's better to use the `ModelCriteria` and its API. Read the following doc for more information: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html